# imageWithcontentsOfFile failing to load saved image from simulator cache dir

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm writing an image to the simulators cache directory using

```
NSURL *cacheDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory 
                                                         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject;
NSURL *avatarFileURL = [cacheDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png" isDirectory:NO];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(avatarImage);
[imageData writeToURL:avatarFileURL atomically:YES];
```

This works fine and I've verified the image by logging the `avatarFile` url and loading it into a browser, which displays the cache image.

I then try and read the test image back and I'm getting different results if I use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and `imageWithData:` as follows:

```
NSURL *cacheDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory 
                                                         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].lastObject;
NSURL *avatarFileURL = [cacheDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png" isDirectory:NO];
// Returns a nil.
NSString *avatarFile = avatarFileUrl.absoluteString;
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:avatarFile]; 

// Returns the image.
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:avatarFileUrl];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

I'm at a loss to explain why `imageWithContentsOfFile` fails and `imageWithData` works when they are both addressing the same URL. I've verified the URL by logging it and urls are exactly the same.

Anyone know why `imageWithContentsOfFile` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
NSString *avatarFile = avatarFileUrl.absoluteString;
```

Look at the value of `avatarFile`. It will be something like `file:///....`. `imageWithContentsOfFile:` expects a proper file path, not a file URL.

You need to properly convert the file URL into a path. That is done as follows:

```
NSString *avatarFile = avatarFileUrl.path;
```

Comment: Now I feel really stupid for not spotting that :-) Thanks.